# Downloading a file using Windows CMD line with curl/wget

Tags: windows, http, command-line-interface, curl, wget

I have a client [Windows 10 VM] and a server [say a linux based VM].

I have Apache running on the Linux Server.

I have a file on the linux server that I want to download on my windows client.

I want to do it in 2 ways from the windows CMD:
-Using curl
-using wget

I tried the foll commands on my windows CMD. But doesnt work. Is something wrong with my CLI?

```
curl http://x.x.x.x/home/abc/ -O test.zip
wget http://x.x.x.x/home/abc/ -O test.zip
```

Edit:: Insense, I wanted to understand the right CLI syntax to do a wget/curl to fetch a file from a certain directory on the remote server (/home/abc)

Comment: Please explain "doesn't work".

Comment: @MassimoEdit:: Insense, I wanted to understand the right CLI syntax to do a wget/curl to fetch a file from a certain directory on the remote server (/home/abc)

Comment: `wget` is not a standard Windows command; `curl` actually is (at least since Windows 10 1803), and you can have a look at its syntax using `curl --help`.

Comment: Also, if you are using PowerShell, both commands are aliases for `Invoke-WebRequest`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retrieve a file stored on another server, you will prefer to use a tool like SCP which can get files throught SSH. Curl is commonly used for Web requests.

The syntax for SCP is `scp myuser@src_server:/home/abc/distantfile.zip ./localfile.zip`

Graphicly, you can use [WinSCP](https://winscp.net)

Answer (score 0):

No third party required, you can use PowerShell command Invoke-WebRequest.

Example:
`Invoke-WebRequest http://x.x.x.x/home/abc/ -OutFile test.zip`

There are additional arguments for adding headers, specifying authentication, and so forth.